# Are cookies written to client machine in OutProc session management in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies

Is cookieless session is only meant for InProc Session, can we write Cookieless = 'true' in OutProc Session. Are cookies are written to the client machine in OutProc Session? Is unique session ID is inserted into the page's URL in OutProc Session management when cookieless = 'true' is set in the web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.you can use cookieless session in OutProc as well

2.yes cookies created on client machine in OutProc session as well

3.yes cookieless works same as inproc for outproc as well

[see details here](https://sameercode.wordpress.com/tag/cookieless-session/)